# How to get ALL product names and keywords from Aliexpress with API?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, aliexpress

I want to get ALL product names and keywords from Aliexpress and put them into CSV file for example, is there any way to do that? I did not find any solution yet. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

-- you can use python with and aliexpress api
go and visite https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=118193&docType=1 for more informations

this is my test code if it can help in someway

```py
from topsdk.client import TopApiClient,TopException
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup #for dicts searchs
import pandas as pd
import json

def get_ali_product():
    # create Client
    client = TopApiClient(appkey='#####get yours', app_sercet='######## get yours', top_gateway_url='http://gw.api.taobao.com/router/rest',verify_ssl=False)
    request_dict = {
        #'fields':'product_detail_url',
        'keywords': 'smart technology',
        'max_sale_price': '500',
        'min_sale_price': '70',
        'page_no':'3',
        'page_size': '2',
        #'platform_product_type':'TMALL',
        'sort': 'SALE_PRICE_ESC' ,
        'target_currency':'USD',
        'target_language':'EN',
        'tracking_id':'finderpool',
        #'ship_to_country':'US',
        #'delivery_days':'3'
        }
    file_param_dict = {}
    #  填充文件类型入参（如有）
    try:
        response = client.execute("aliexpress.affiliate.product.query",request_dict,file_param_dict)
        json_object = json.dumps(response , indent = 2) 
        return(json_object)
        #print(response['resp_result']['result']['products'][0]['product_detail_url'])
        #return nested_lookup('product_detail_url', response)
    except TopException as e:
        print(e)


print(get_ali_product())
```